# Play framework 2: Eclipse cant detect jBCrypt as project dependency

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, dependency-management

I am trying to use jBCrypt to start securing my passwords more effectively but I dont know why eclipse doenst detect my project dependency: I have added at least following:

**plugins.sbt**

```
resolvers += "jBCrypt Repository" at "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/"
```

**Build.scala**

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
      // Add your project dependencies here,
      "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18",
      "org.mindrot" % "jbcrypt" % "0.3m"
    )
```

**SecurityUtils.java (testing to import)**

import org.mindrot... <- not recognized.. when i type just **org.** and view list of packages there is not mindrot...

When I try at terminal **play dependencies** I can see that module *org.mindrot:jbcrypt:0.3m* is successfully loaded and its required by "testProject:testProject_2.9.1:1.0" As jbcrypt-0.3m.jar

Same .jar package can be found when browsing it via finder of Mac. (inside cache of play repository folder).

I have also tried to refresh eclipse among running play clean, compile, ~run etc. but with no luck. What could be the problem? This is play framework 2.0.2 java project.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems that generating eclipse configurations again middle of other play commands solved the problem and package is now recognized. I used following commands:

```
play clean
play compile
play eclipsify
play ~run
```

This doesnt seem fair that we should create new eclipse project files when we add new dependency? but I guess I need to stick with this if there is no other opinions how to solve similar case? thnx in advance.

**Edit:**

Heads up! `eclipsify` command has been replaced by `eclipse` in recent versions of sbt.

Comment: thanks, spent an hour trying to figure out why eclipse is showing an older version of a lib i added to Build.scala. This is a pain point using play with eclipse.

Comment: np. glad that could help, went through some frustrating moments myself too when solving this.

Comment: thanks, had exactly the same problem with play and jbcrypt. Glad to find your solution

Comment: I don't know if it's because the new releases of play, but if you put `resolvers += "jBCrypt Repository" at "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/"` in Build.scala instead of plugins.sbt and then clean & compile, eclipse will recognize it